# Upload video to youtube from Firebase Storage using cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Can I upload video to my youtube channel from firebase storage using cloud function. There is no restriction on the function triggering which means the function can be triggered by any method like HTTP trigger/cron job/Firebase Call function. I did not find any code related to this yet.Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs), however I checked it shortly and I think it will be hard or even impossible to do it as general with no limits. When I looked on [Firebase Quotas page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) there is a quota that might limit such idea.
Cloud Function is has hard time limit of 540 seconds. I think that might be some movies that you are able to download within 9 minutes, however for sure most of youtube contents will not be possible  to be uploaded in such time.

Other problem is that I do not found any possibility to upload without local file system. Firebase function does not use local file system only has possibility to use in memory `tmp` directory, which means that it's affecting total memory usage which is limited by quota of 4GB. Not much for video purposes as well.

So in my opinion, it maybe possible to upload small video using cloud function, but I don't think you will be able to upload larger content.

Comment: Can you show me some code for if I want to upload small video say up to 1 mins? Again thanks for the answer that you have given.

Comment: Well, as I written im not very familiar within YouTube API, so it will be too time consuming especially, that I don't think this is good idea to even try to do it. Why do you want to do it in Cloud Function?

Comment: I am developing an app where the users can upload videos to my youtube channel and then the video will be displayed to users. Is there any other way than Youtube data API because Youtube Data API also has quota limitations for uploading a video. It consumes a 1600 quota per upload.